# Creating new copy of Infopath form to allow user to resubmit to library as new copy

Tags: infopath, form, infopath-rules, read-only, status

I created a form in which once in status approved I am planning on having a new view which would be read only for the customer. Our customers need to have access to the library to look at their requests and some times revise the requests.

I was thinking that also based upon the status to create a button that will allow the user to select it to allow the user to have a new copy of the form and allow them to make a revision to the scope and when they submit it, it will submit as a new submission rather than a update to the original. Can anyone tell me how to do this or the rules I would need to do it? If someone has an idea that would be easier to do please suggest away.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) The first thing you need to do is disable the save/save as buttons, and instead of using those on your form, use a custom submit button (no code) by following the blog entry:  [Auto-Generating Filenames for InfoPath Forms](http://claytoncobb.com/2009/06/20/auto-generating-filenames-for-infopath-forms/).

2) Then, add a 2nd button that does the same thing, but make it so that this either uses a separate submit data connection with a different filename (could just concatenate some text with the now() function on the fly) or that performs some other logic of defining your new filename before submitting with the previous submit data connection

3) When a form has already been submitted, this new button will show up, and you can name it "Copy Form."  Pushing that button will submit a new XML file to the library with a different name.  Pressing the other button will update the current form.  You can add logic to show or hide either or both buttons depending on the user or status of the form.

I found the answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c5e5fb5-62da-4b34-826b-b03927bd7c2a/copy-an-existing-infopath-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy).